# reading a hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat hive table in spark

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table in hadoop, which has an output format of

```
hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
```

I am reading this table using the spark sql

```
spark.sql('select * from testtable where y = 2021 and month = 12 and day =12')
```

The spark job runs super slow, i have tried adjusting the number of executors and memory per executor, but nothing seems to improve the performance. I read on a blog that SequenceFile are not the best when it comes to hive table.

Is there a better way of reading this table ?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: thang single partition of day have 64 tb data @MattAndruff

Comment: I'm sorry, 64Tb in a single partition or 64 Tb per partition (per day)?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [partitioning](https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-hive/hive-partitions-explained-with-examples/) your table by date if you will continue to access it regularly by date.  (Lookups on the partition will be very fast, at the cost of queries that don't use partions).

You should also look into the "[small files problem](https://blog.cloudera.com/the-small-files-problem/)" with hadoop.  You can get some nice speed out of making files larger.

You should look at using Parquet or Orc.  They're compress nicely and often boost performance.

You should also look at running [table stats](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/performance-tuning/content/hive_generate_hive_statistics.html) on the hive table, this also helps to increase performance.